# Dual system on one SSD, and failed to boot into ubuntu installed on another disk( mobile disk)

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, dual-boot

Dual system on one SSD(Intel), Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. And this computer cant boot ubuntu installed on another disk. And I install another Ubuntu 18.04 on mobile disk(Seagate), it works fine on the computer that install the system, however cant work on this computer.
grub2 menu shows the entry of ubuntu in Seagate(/dev/sda1), entering it then jump to emergency mode.
I typed `cat /etc/fstab`, and 3 partitions( /, /home, swap) is on `/dev/sda`,but `/boot/efi` is on SSD. It is a freshly installed system, I can take it reinstalling again to make ubuntu on Seagate operates in more computers.

Comment: You have to partition external drive in advance and include an ESP - efi system partition. UEFI on external drives only boots from /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. You can copy the entire folders /EFI/Boot & /EFI/ubuntu from internal drive to external. You need both as bootx64.efi with full install need additional files in /EFI/ubuntu. Or you can totally reinstall grub. Or you reconfigure ESP mount during install. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379

Comment: Many thanks first @oldfred. From my understanding, it is unmount from internal ESP partition, and mount external **ESP** partition to `/boot/efi`; Then run `sudo grub-install`, `sudo update-grub`. However, I tried it twice found that ubuntu go to emergency mode when I boot from another computer. I think I have to find another way round.

Comment: Are both systems UEFI or both systems BIOS? Generally better to be same as not straight forward to make a system boot both ways. But several threads do post how-to if that is a real requirement.

Comment: Both computer is UEFI booting. They are 64bits and state-of-art computers, so traditional BIOS booting is not primary but compatible.

Comment: Partitioning: UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation
Install: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167910/unable-to-properly-boot-linux-from-external-ssd/1167940#1167940 &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/913716/dual-boot-on-seperate-drives-best-configuration

Comment: I think I have go through these blogs. In conclusion, I made steps below so that boot the ubuntu from one disk, and I successfully create a removable operation system. 1. copy files in ```/boot/efi``` from /nvme0n1p1, to /dev/sda1 (it is the ESP partition in Seagate), of course i mounted the partition early before copy efi files. 2. register EFI booting entry with efibootmgr( I also use EasyUEFI in windows platform to modify entry) 3. modify /etc/fstab, for initiate mount point when you boot ubuntu. Then it is all done, you can take the disk and boot from computers with UEFI firmware.

Comment: You may have missed the change in fstab to have UUID of ESP on external drive. Then updates would use that UUID, not the original install UUID of the internals drive's ESP.